# From where the FB Messenger Contents are getting

Tags: facebook, share, messenger

For geeks in FB messenger sharing:

Anyone knows, from where is content getting on website when you share it via FB messenger?

Comment: Same as when you share it on Facebook directly - the Open Graph meta tags the URL returns.

Comment: I also thought like that but in my case, the description does not come from og tags. I can't even find the text came from where either

Comment: I think we found the solution. It's caching on FB thank for your time!